# How to get full stack trace in sentry?

Tags: vue.js, sentry

I have a vue 2 application. I setup sentry with official @sentry/vue package.
In some issues I can't get full detailed stack trace.
[This issue](https://sentry.io/share/issue/0e398f430f874ff381cfa781e8af6b20/) has a good stack trace. I can click and see the exact line in my code.
[image]

But in [this issue](https://sentry.io/share/issue/0d2d1c9f514646de9fd42b2b3c23468d/#exception) I can't do it.
[image]

I don't understand why In the first case sentry saved a few lines of code from chunk-app-vendors.xxx.js, but it didn't save code in the second issue.
I don't have access to this file, because my application has already been updated.

How can I solve this problem to see more data about errors?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because your project lacks sourcemap, and cannot locate the specific error location? You need to upload the sourcemap.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry doesn't generate and doesn't upload sourcemaps by default.
In particular, the whole process consists of:

- generating the sourcemaps
- uploading them to Sentry
- validating them (on sentry)

I suggest you to read the related section of their [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/vue/sourcemaps/).